# Find the volume of a sphere whose area is 180 square meters. *

Tags: area

How would you begin to solve this?

Do you use $A = 4\pi r^2$?

$V = \frac43\pi r^3$.

Substitute $180$ for $A$, solve for $r$ and plug into Volume equation(leave in simplified form).

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right.

Comment: I get some weird equation like 4/3 * root45/pi ^3 * pi not sure if I am on the right track

Comment: Yea that looks around right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formulas:
$$A = 4 \pi r^2$$
and
$$V = \frac43 \pi r^3$$ We get that $$V = \frac{A^{\frac32}}{6\sqrt{\pi}}\tag{Quite a known formula}$$
Substitute the values of $A$ and you get:
$$\frac{180^{\frac32}}{6\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 227.081$$

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to notice that $A^3 = 64 \pi^3 r^6$ and $V^2 = \frac{16}{9} \pi^2 r^6$.

Therefore

$$\frac{V^2}{A^3} = \frac{1}{36 \pi}$$ and $$V = \frac{A^{3/2}}{6 \sqrt \pi} \approx 227.1$$

Which avoids to solve $r$ from $A$.

Comment: Downvoter, an explanation would be welcomed!

Comment: I didn't downvote, maybe cause I asked in simplified form?